# RxJava Backpressure (Fast producer slow consumer)

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java

i have execution method which does some time consuming network calls on io thread

example

```
/**
 * network call
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
private Observable<Integer> execute(final int value) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("done " + value);
            subscriber.onNext(value);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

then i have list of "commands" which must be executed in order. (one after another)

example (Observable.range(x,y) represents list of commands)

```
public List<Integer> testObservableBackpressure(){
   return Observable.range(0,5).flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("started " + integer);
            return exeute(integer);
        }
    }).toList().toBlocking().single();
}
```

in this way out put is

```
started 0
started 1
started 2
started 3
started 4
done 0
done 1
done 2
done 4
done 3
```

Produses faster than is consuming

I want results like that

```
started 0
done 0
started 1
done 1
started 2
done 2
...
```

but..

```
public List<Integer> testObservableBackpressure(){

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
            Observable.range(0,5).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    request(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    System.out.println("started " + integer);
                    execute(integer).subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Integer integer) {
                            subscriber.onNext(integer);
                            request(1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).toList().toBlocking().single();
}
```

this way results are as expected

```
started 0
done 0
started 1
done 1
started 2
done 2
started 3
done 3
started 4
```

My question would be if there is another more elegant way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you need any particular backpressure strategy here. Just use `concatMap`.

If you use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`, each new input value will only subscribe when the last `Observable` emitted from the `concatMap` completes. Under the hood, `concatMap` uses a `SerialSubscription` for this. That should give you the ordering you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Results as expected

Answer (score 1):

The output that I get when I run your code is:

```
started 0
started 1
started 2
started 3
started 4
done 1
done 3
done 4
done 2
done 0
```

Notice that the "done" messages are out of order. This is due to the fact that your code basically parallelises the execution of each call to `execute`. For each item emitted by the `Observable.range` you `flatMap` an `Observable` that runs on its own `IOScheduler`. Thus every item is handled in parallel on separate threads which makes it impossible for the items to stay in order and correctly interleaved. One option to achieve the desired behaviour is to make sure that all items run on the same `IOScheduler` (instead of each item on its own):

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private Observable<Integer> execute(final int value) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("done " + value);
                subscriber.onNext(value);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }

    public List<Integer> testObservableBackpressure(){
        return Observable.range(0, 5).flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Integer> call(Integer integer) {
                System.out.println("started " + integer);
                return execute(integer);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).toList().toBlocking().single();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testObservableBackpressure();
    }
}
```

Notice that the only difference is where you invoke the `subscribeOn` operator. This code results in the following output:

```
started 0
done 0
started 1
done 1
started 2
done 2
started 3
done 3
started 4
done 4
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, its one of the solutions.
but mostly i have to execute 1 command, so i usually call only execute(command), so its need to run on io thread, but in some cases i need to execute list of commands and sync their execution.
Your solution is fine, but after every execute(command) must be added .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())